# Sessions not working on CDN but works on localhost

Tags: php, session, cdn, php-7

Code works well on localhost, but when i deployed it on hosting that is using CDN,
the PHP session is not working.

On page1, I have form that is using token

```
<form method='post' action='page2'>
   <input type='hidden' name='token' value='someRandomToken'>
</form>
```

On page2, it will validate the token

```
if($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'])
{
    do something
}
```

It looks like the $_SESSION['token'] is blank

EDIT

> I guess the problem is not because of CDN and hosting, I guess it's because of PHP version? I am using PHP Version 7.2.34 and still can't make SESSION and COOKIES work

Comment: Have you started session? What is session_status value?

Comment: If session works on localhost but not remote, check php session folder location has proper owner n permissions on remote host

Comment: @JoelCrypto i did session_start(); at the very beginning. print_r($_SESSION) shows empty array

Comment: It is not the version it is a CDN configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of placement of **$_SESSION["variable"]**

It must be set before you print / echo anything.

I thought only the **session_start()** must be place above any prints.

```
<?php

//do not print / echo anything above 

session_start();
$_SESSION["variable"] = "some value";
```